# C: Assert that an expression is a string literal

Tags: c, gcc, string-literals, static-assert

I would like a static assertion to be sure that a given expression is a string literal. I tried this:

```
#define SAME_TYPES(x, y)                    __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), typeof(y))
#define IS_ARRAY(x)                         !SAME_TYPES((x), &(x)[0])
#define IS_COMPILE_TIME_STR(x)              IS_ARRAY(x) && #x[0] == '"'
#define ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_STR(x)          static_assert(IS_COMPILE_TIME_STR(x), "Only static allocated compile time strings are allowed, but got this: " #x)

/*
 * ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_STR("hey"); <-- this is fine
 * ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_STR(1234);  <-- this should fail
 */
```

Unfortunately, `ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_STR` does not work, because `#x[0] == '"'` does not seem to be a compile-time-constant.

Is there some other way to achieve this? It just has to compile with gcc, so any kind of extensions are fine:)

Thanks a lot

Comment: The method is flawed; you cannot detect whether something is an array using `x[0]` because not every type has a subscript operator. C is the wrong language for this kind of stuff.

Comment: The subscript operator is applied to the stringified version of the expression. E.g. for x=123, it will evaluate to "123"[0]. So `#x[0]` is actually always well-defined (even at compile-time).

Comment: Not the subscript operator in `&(x)[0]`, that one is applied straight to `1234` which is why your code fails to compile.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Failing to compile is a detection that the subject is not a string literal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you fail to compile there, then what is the point of the whole static assertion? Plus that in itself isn't the right test, it only tests whether something has a subscript operator. Failing to compile is easy. Failing to compile with good diagnostics and correctness is hard. Probably too hard for C.

Comment: @JanSchultke: The primary goal is apparently for compilation to succeed if `x` is a string literal and to fail if it is not. It would be nice if the failure is a static assertion explicitly stating the failure is due to `x` not being a string literal, but any failure may be acceptable. So that is the point of the static assertion and the reason why other failures may be acceptable.

Comment: @JanSchultke: That `x[0]` only tests whether `x` has a subscript operator is okay because it will not be the only test. From memory, I think there is another question on Stack Overflow about detecting arrays. However, testing for a string literal is harder.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it's not really a test if it fails to compile when the test fails. If you considered that a test, OP should just write `ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_STRING(x) (void) sizeof(x[0])` (and a few other expressions in there) and call it a day. I'd only consider something that can yield `true` or `false` a test.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Yes, it is really a test. Re “I'd only consider something that can yield `true` or `false` a test.”: You can consider a test whatever you want, but OP asks for a static assertion, which does not just produce a true or false result. It causes a compilation error or does not cause a compilation error, so that appears to be the outcome that OP wants. It is more important what the actual goal being sought is than what you want the words to mean.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the actual goal seems to be getting a sane diagnostic, because the question involves a `static_assert` with a meaningful error message. It is more important to answer in the spirit of the question than to seek a perceived goal at all cost.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Re “the actual goal seems to be getting a sane diagnostic”: That is different from what you said before, where you said “I'd only consider something that can yield `true` or `false` a test.” As I have written, most likely the OP would like an explicit statement that the failure is due to the tested item not being a string literal, but that might not be possible within the facilities provided by the C standard or GCC, and any compilation failure might be acceptable. Further, documenting the issue at the point of the test would provide the necessary information,…

Comment: … as anybody investigating the failure would look at the source code and see the documentation there explaining that a compilation failure at that point is due to the item not being a string literal. Do you have any reason to believe that, if a complete test solely in a static assertion cannot be provided, then a test that causes a compilation error would not suffice?

Comment: @EricPostpischil no, it's not different from what I've said before, because getting a condition that yields `true` or `false` is a prerequisite for `static_assert`. I believe that if a string literal is needed in code and one won't be provided, something else will typically fail to compile. The reason why you would even want to test for this is to get better diagnostics. Getting some bizarre syntax error that turns out to be `STATIC_ASSERT_XYZ` only when you dig deep enough through the error messages is much less desirable than a proper error message.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Re “only when you dig deep enough through the error messages“: No, that is not the scenario posited. The scenario is you do as best you can in the static assert, but then you additionally put something there that will definitely trigger some error, any error, at that point. And when the error occurs, nobody needs to “dig deep enough through error messages,” because all that is needed is to look at the line of source code the error is reported on because at that point is a prominent comment explaining exactly what the issue is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you have a `static_assert` and the *condition* of the assertion has a syntax error when expanding a macro, that looks like a developer mistake. And yes, people will have to dig deep through the error messages and possibly some comments on the macro to realize that compilation failure of the condition is intentional. It's just bad and confusing, no idea why anyone would defend this.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Re “if … that looks like a developer mistake“: Not if the reason for the syntax error is that the desired condition is not possible given the facilities provided by the C standard and GCC, so the error condition was created out of necessity, not out of design choice. I have repeatedly stated that.

Comment: @JanSchultke:  Re “no idea why anyone would defend this”: That is not a valid argument; whether you have an idea or not does not speak to the merits of some option. If you want to argue some thing X should not be done, then you show some better way Y and show how it is better, not assert you have no idea why X should be done. But the premise here is that X is done because there is no alternative Y. As I have repeatedly explained, if the Y you want were possible, that would be preferred. If there is no Y, then we accept X.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's a false dichotomy. There are many things that you can *technically* do in C, especially with the preprocessor, but the solution would be so unergonomic that the solution becomes a bigger problem than the problem itself. Producing extremely poor diagnostics through intentional syntax errors is one of those cases. If your goal is to punch your way through a brick wall with bare hands, maybe you should consider an alternative rather than figuring out the best way to swing your fist.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Re “that's a false dichotomy”: What is a false dichotomy? Re “so unergonomic… extremely poor diagnostics”: These are figments of your imagination, not actual choices at the moment. You are arguing about unmanifested hypotheticals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C allows consecutive string constants which the compiler combines into a single constant.  You can exploit this by attempting to put a string constant in line with the expression in question.

```
#define IS_STR_CONT(x) (void)((void)(x),&(""x""))
```

A few notes about the above:

- The `(x)` on the left side of the comma operator helps to catch certain types of non-expressions such as `0+`
- Taking the address ensures that the result is an lvalue
- The `void` cast on both the left side of the comma operator and the full expression prevent warnings about an expression with no effect.

The above accepts this with no warning or error:

```
IS_STR_CONT("hello");
```

While generating one or more errors with these:

```
IS_STR_CONT(123);
IS_STR_CONT(0+);
IS_STR_CONT(+0);
int i=0;
IS_STR_CONT((i++,"xxx"));
IS_STR_CONT(!"abc");
IS_STR_CONT(4 + "abc");
IS_STR_CONT(*"abc");
IS_STR_CONT("ad" == "abc");
```

This isn't perfect, but should catch most cases.

Comment: This will need to be combined with other tests to exclude non-string-literal possibilities for which `IS_STR_CONT(x)` does not cause an error, including empty, some expressions (like `(void) 0, "a"`), a cast like `(void)` or other partial expressions like `0+`, and weirder things like `0);(` (which cannot directly be an argument to `IS_STR_CONT`, but you could `#define Y 0);(` and then pass `Y` to `IS_STR_CONT`).

Comment: Surveying the grammar, there are plenty of expressions that pass that test, including `E, S` where `E` is an expression and `S` is a string literal, `sizeof S`, `E ? E : S`, `!S`, `&S`, `*S`, `(T) S` where `T` is a type, `E + S`, `S < S` and the other relational and equality operators, `0 == S`, `0 != S`, `S && S`, `S || S`, `E = S` and the other assignment operators, and expressions built from those, such as `3 + *S`. A few of those are effectively a string literal (`E, S` is effectively `S` if not confounded in some way) but most are not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good points.  Added some extra checks as well as a caveat at the end.

Comment: @chqrlie Added a case for that as well.

Comment: Taking the address is an excellent fix!